# Can I get 'this' element from rxjs observable when source is a class

Tags: jquery, this, rxjs, observable

I am doing the fromEvent on click from an observable, however, I want to get the data attribute from the element that gave the event. I'been trying to use this from within with no success. How can I achieve the normal 'this' from jquery

```
var elem = $(".someElementClass");
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(elem, 'click');
var subscription = source.subscribe(function (e) {
var x = $(this).attr("data-toget");
alert(x);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside callback does not refer to `jQuery` object, like for example in `$.each`., in this case you can use `$(e.currentTarget)` instead of `$(this)`

```js
var elem = $(".someElementClass");
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(elem, 'click');
var subscription = source.subscribe(function (e) {
  console.log($(e.currentTarget).attr("data-toget"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<button class="someElementClass" data-toget="100">Button-1</button>
<button class="someElementClass" data-toget="200">Button-2</button>
<button class="someElementClass" data-toget="300">Button-3</button>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, can't upvote since is new account.